# Should a question be marked as duplicate, even if the new one is better?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question "[Why can I log in to my Facebook account with a misspelled email/password?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/214814/why-can-i-log-in-to-my-facebook-account-with-a-misspelled-email-password)" was asked yesterday, and a very well-written answer gathered nearly 200 upvotes in about a day (I assume the question went to HNQ).

Roughly 16 hours ago, the question was marked as duplicate of "[Facebook password lowercase and uppercase](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68013/facebook-password-lowercase-and-uppercase)", which is in essence the same question. The answer to this question comes to the same conclusion, but somewhat lacks depth and - more importantly - does not cite an official source.

Is this question still considered a duplicate? Or should the older question be marked as a duplicate of the newer, better question (which I have seen several times happen already for this very reason).

Comment: I was debating this question myself yesterday.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If a newer question encompasses a wider and a more detailed field of view, then I think it could be the core question and the older one made a dupe.

In your example, the older question really only focuses on the capital letters, which could be explained by the password mechanism doing an `upper()` or `lower()` function. The newer question blows the scope wide open, which makes it far more interesting and more impactful.

So, I would vote to make the older one a dupe of the newer one.